# NODE.js com socket e MySql

Tags: node.js

estou com um problema com o node, acredito que deve ser algo relacionado a callback´s, porém não tenho certeza, mais enfim, meu problema se resuma basicamente em puxar os dados de um banco **MySql**, esses dados serão armazenados em uma variável chamada **msg**. Meu código completo é este:

```
        const express = require('express');
        const path = require('path');
        const app = express();
        const server = require('http').createServer( app );
        const io = require('socket.io')(server);
        const mysql = require('mysql');

        // conexao com o banc﻿o de dados 
        var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "dados_users"
        });


        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
        app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'public'));


        app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
        app.set('view engine','html');

        app.use('/', ( request , res ) => {
            res.render('index.html');
        });

        let msg =[];  

        io.on('connection', socket => {

        //este select deve retornar as mensagens que estão no banco para a 
        //variavel msg
        // con.connect(function(err) {
        //     con.query('SELECT * FROM dados', function(err, rows, fields) {
        //         if (err) throw err;
        //           msg = rows;
        //     });
        // });

        socket.emit('msg_existentes',msg);    //retorna dados earmazenados na variavel msg 
        socket.on('recebe_do_front', data => {



        console.log(msg);

        // con.connect(function(err) {
        //     var sql = "INSERT INTO dados (nome, msg) VALUES ('"+data.nome+"', '"+data.msg+"')";
        //     con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        //     if (err) throw err;
        //         console.log("1 record inserted");
        //     });
        // });

        msg.push( data );     //manter msg na section da pagina
        socket.broadcast.emit('envia_para_usuario', data);   //retorna msg do canudo 
    });
});
server.listen(3001);
```

A função que não esta fazendo a parte dela é a função de [ select ], esta abaixo:

```
   //este select deve retornar as mensagens que estão no banco para a 
  //variavel msg
  con.connect(function(err) {
       con.query('SELECT * FROM dados', function(err, rows, fields) {
           if (err) throw err;
                 msg = rows;
       });
    });
```

então é isso, quando é executado o programa, ele trás a variável msg vazia. Desde já Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Estude sobre assincronismo no node e sua relação com callbacks.
O código não está sendo executado na sequência que você está pensando.

```
let msg =[];  

io.on('connection', socket => {

    con.connect(function(err) {

        con.query('SELECT * FROM dados', function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // [1]
            msg = rows;
            socket.emit('msg_existentes',msg);
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Leandro, cara dessa forma, o cod entra em loop e fica dando um warnings                                `websocket.js:234 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=v_OEjrUil-xkVarwAABm' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.`

Comment: @FabricioCarneiro este já é outro erro, que pode ser causado por outros motivos.

Comment: @Leandro, cara eu estudei mais a fundo e entendi as cacas kkk, cara deu tudo certo, muito obrigado ai pela força mano.